# Stochastic differential equation of a falling body

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

It's well known the motion of a falling body in a constant gravity model, for high speed is given by:
$$m\ddot{x}(t)=g-\beta\dot{x}(t)^2$$
where $\beta$ is he drag coefficient.
In a turbolent flow we can assume the drag coefficient $\beta$ is a gaussian distribuited random variable around a mean value $\beta_0$. So the previous equation becomes:
$$m\ddot{x}(t)=g-\beta(t)\dot{x}(t)^2$$
where $\beta(t)=N(\beta_0,\sigma)$
How can the last equation be solved assuming thi behaviour of $\beta(t)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you worked with Langevin  equations before?

Comment: @Chinny84: yes. Is it a Langevin equation?